# Function not providing the correct output

Tags: c, function

My assignment is to write a program that reads input as a stream of characters until encountering EOF using redirection. Have the program report the number of words and the average number of letters per word.

```
int main(void)
{
int  ch, wordCount, wordAverage, letterCount;
bool inword = false;
wordCount = 0;
letterCount = 0;

while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if (isalpha(ch)) 
    {
        letterCount++;

        if (!isspace(ch) && (!inword))
        {
            inword = true;
            wordCount++;
        }
    }

    else
        inword = false;

}
wordAverage = letterCount / wordCount;

printf("The number of words was %d, and the average letters per word was 
%d.", wordCount, wordAverage);

}
```

The code outputs the wrong word count, I assume the average word length is correct. It is registering don't as 2 words not 1.

Comment: What does it print? What do you expect it to print? What is your input?

Comment: You have your `isspace` check inside the `isalpha` check. I think you should use a debugger.

Comment: The word count is 161, but it should output 155.

Comment: I would remember the current state of the input: alpha or space. Then you can increment the word count when it *changes* from alpha to space (or from alpha to EOF). You can then tolerate several consecutive non-alpha characters like punctuation, spaces and newlines without distorting the word count.

Comment: How would that translate to my code?

Comment: So it's registering words like Don't as 2 instead of 1.

Comment: In that case you'll can define a string of characters that you consider to be part of a "word" and use `strchr()` to see if the current character is in the string. Or a combination; is the character a letter, or in this other group of characters.

Comment: isalpha returns false on ' so "don't" will be treated as two words "don" and "t". think about the problem as counting the first space between words, maybe that is easier.